# Subriber Birthday customer sync

Tags: php, magento, subscriber, date

I have a problem for which I cannot find the right answer.
In Magento I want to add the DOB to the newsletter-subscribers.
I succesfully did, by following this tutorial:

http://www.iamrookie.com/blog/159/add-custo-field-in-newsletter-module-magento.html

So now I see a DOB-row in my database and in my backend from Magento. And if I set a date in the database (I’m not testing with the sign-up form) I see the right value.

The only thing I want to do is to check of the customer has set an DOB in his profile. If so, I want to override the value in the database with his DOB.

This should be possible because you also see the first and last name of the customer in the backend.

I believe the file where I should change it is the subscriber.php. I tried different thing already, but nothing is working.

I think I should do something here:

```
/**
     * Load subscriber info by customer
     *
     * @param Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer
     * @return Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber
     */
    public function loadByCustomer(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer)
    {
        $data = $this->getResource()->loadByCustomer($customer);
        $this->addData($data);
        if (!empty($data) && $customer->getId() && !$this->getCustomerId()) {
            $this->setCustomerId($customer->getId());

            $this->setSubscriberConfirmCode($this->randomSequence());
            if ($this->getStatus()==self::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE) {
                $this->setStatus($customer->getIsSubscribed() ? self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED : self::STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED);
            }
            $this->save();
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Or here:

```
/**
     * Retrieve Subscribers Full Name if it was set
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getSubscriberFullName()
    {
        $name = null;
        if ($this->hasCustomerFirstname() || $this->hasCustomerLastname()) {
            $name = $this->getCustomerFirstname() . ' ' . $this->getCustomerLastname();
        }
        return $name;
    }
```

But I really don’t know. If somebody has any idea how to get this done, I really would appreciate it!

Comment: Magento has its own StackExchange site: [magento.se]. You should ask there.

Comment: Thank you. I will do that and search there!